# Queueing tasks to run one after the other

Tags: c#, queue, task, semaphore

I have a scenario where I want to perform a long running operation as task on a worker thread, to produce a result that will be displayed on the UI thread.

However, the service being used for the long operation is not thread safe, and only one task should be using it at any one time (I cannot change this service, so have to work with it as is). I also have to handle the case where many requests can come in quick succession. In my case, I only care about the last submitted request, any previous requests should be cancelled/ignored (if possible).

For example, if 5 requests come in one after the other, then the first 4 should ideally be cancelled and only the last used and displayed. If one of those tasks has already started, then it will have to be waited on until completion (as the service cannot be cancelled), but the result simply ignored and not displayed.

I was previously doing this with a BlockingCollection to implement a Queue. Which works fine, but I wasn't happy with having to have a dedicated thread for the BlockingCollection loop (there will be many of these instances in flight at a time). So am trying another approach.

The idea being that whenever a new request comes in, a Task is kicked off, but to handle the requirement that only one task can use the service at any one time, I use a Semaphore with a resource count of 1. And to handle the case of "out of date" requests being ignored, I simply pass in the cancelation token to the Semaphore WaitAsync, such that most tasks will be cancelled before even reaching the point where the service is used. So the cases where we have to wait for an outdated request that has already started will be minimal.

To me this seems like quite a clean solution to the problem, but am left with the issue of how to dispose of the CancelationTokenSources? I can't think of a clean way to handle them? so am looking for suggestions.

```
internal partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private CancellationTokenSource? _lastCancellation;
    private Service _service = new Service();
    private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string _queryResult;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool _isLoading;

    public async Task Refresh(string query)
    {
        _lastCancellation?.Cancel();

        var cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _lastCancellation = cancel;

        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancel.Token);

                try
                {
                    IsLoading = true;

                    _service.Query = query;
                    _service.Process();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _semaphore.Release();
                    IsLoading = false;
                }
            }, cancel.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // ignore
            cancel.Dispose();
            Debug.WriteLine($"{query} was cancelled.");
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            // an exception was thrown from the service
            Debug.WriteLine("Error = " + ex.Message);
            QueryResult = "Error = " + ex.Message;
            return;
        }

        // don't update the UI for requests that were cancelled
        if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            cancel.Dispose();
            Debug.WriteLine($"{query} was started before it could be cancelled (ignoring)");
            return;
        }

        QueryResult = _service.Result;
        Debug.WriteLine("*** Accepted = " + QueryResult);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Service is NOT thread safe and I cannot change its interface
/// </summary>
internal class Service
{
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; private set; }

    public void Process()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Start " + Query);

        string query = Query;

        // simulate long running task
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Result = query + "#";

        Debug.WriteLine("End " + Result);
    }
}
```

The above code shows the implementation, and the following code is somewhat of a stress test to make sure it works as expected.

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
     ViewModel.Refresh("Query " + count);
     count++;
}
```

EDIT :

Update to include suggestion by @HABO

```
internal partial class ViewModel2 : ObservableObject
{
    private Service _service = new Service();
    private Task? _runningTask;

    private ConcurrentQueue<string> _queries = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    public string? _queryResult;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public bool _isLoading;

    public async Task Refresh(string query)
    {
        _queries.Enqueue(query);

        if (_runningTask == null || _runningTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                _runningTask = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    IsLoading = true;

                    while (_queries.Any())
                    {
                        // get the last query, ignoring anything else
                        string? lastQuery = null;
                        while (_queries.TryDequeue(out string? nextQuery))
                        {
                            lastQuery = nextQuery;
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            _service.Query = lastQuery;
                            _service.Process();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // we only want to throw if we're processing the last query
                            if (!_queries.Any())
                                throw;
                        }
                    }

                    // There is a race condition here.
                    // Can be seen by adding a Sleep() and then
                    // calling Refresh() during the Sleep() period
                });

                await _runningTask;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // an exception was thrown from the service
                Debug.WriteLine("Error = " + ex.Message);
                QueryResult = "Error = " + ex.Message;
                IsLoading = false;
                return;
            }

            QueryResult = _service.Result;
            Debug.WriteLine("*** Accepted = " + QueryResult);

            IsLoading = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Service is NOT thread safe and I cannot change its interface
    /// </summary>
    private class Service
    {
        public string Query { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; private set; }

        public void Process()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Start " + Query);

            string query = Query;

            // simulate long running task
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //throw new Exception("");

            Result = query + "#";

            Debug.WriteLine("End " + Result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking something more along the lines of a single task and a single static request. That solves the problems of multiple tasks and multiple queued requests. When a request arrives it is put into the static variable and, if the status of the task is not running, the task is started. The task immediately copies the request for internal use. The last thing the task does is check for a new request and either starts processing it or stops. A little locking to protect the request and you should be good to go.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @HABO I've updated the example to include the idea you suggested. Not sure if it has issues with race conditions, so would be good to get some feedback on it?

Comment: You're still queuing all of the requests, only to flush the extraneous ones later. If nothing else you could `.Clear()` the queue in `Refresh` immediately before you `.Enqueue()` the new request. Surrounded by suitable locking, of course,